# Dictionary Key Error

Tags: python-2.7, csv, numpy

I am trying to construct a dictionary with values from a csv file.Say 10 columns there and i want to set the first column as key and the remaining as Values. 
If setting as a for loop the dictionary has to have only one value. Kindly Suggest me a way.

```
import csv
import numpy
aname = {}
#loading the file in numpy
result=numpy.array(list(csv.reader(open('somefile',"rb"),delimiter=','))).astype('string')
#devolop a dict\
r = {aname[rows[0]]: rows[1:] for rows in result}
print r[0]
```

Error as follows.

`r = {aname[rows[0]]: rows[1:] for rows in result}`
`KeyError: '2a9ac84c-3315-5576-4dfd-8bc34072360d|11937055'`

Comment: And when you get this working, what exactly do you imagine printing `r[0]` will accomplish?

Comment: It will Rise a Key error,i know. But the Line is to check it out the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean to do here, but does this help:

```
>>> result = [[1, 'a', 'b'], [2, 'c', 'd']]
>>> dict([(row[0], row[1:]) for row in result])
{1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c', 'd']}
```

Comment: Replace `r = {aname[rows[0]]: rows[1:] for rows in result}` with
`x = dict([(row[0], row[1:]) for row in result])` based on your idea.It Worked.